# How to move the cursor to the end of the read only text?

Tags: motion

Say I have text:

`This read only text ends here>*********************|`

The `This read only text ends here>` is read only while the asterisks are are not. When the `(move-to-read-only-end)` is called, I want the cursor to move right after the `>`. Like this:

`This read only text ends here>|*********************`

How can the `(move-to-read-only-end)` be written?

EDIT: Adding comment here per advice,

"In eshell, the prompt is read only but when you write commands those are not. So, I want to be able to move at the end of the prompt and the start of the commands."

Comment: You first need to tell us what makes that text read-only. Is it that the buffer characters have text-property `read-only`? Or is there an overlay on those buffer positions that has overlay property `read-only`?

Comment: In eshell, the prompt is read only but when you write commands those are not. So, I want to be able to move at the end of the prompt and the start of the commands. Does that make sense?

Comment: OK, please specify that in your question. Comments can be deleted at any time. 
If you put your cursor within the prompt (e.g. using the mouse) and do `C-u C-x =` you'll see that it says that there is a `read-only` *text property* there (which answers my question to you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're asking about `eshell` specifically, you should be able to use the command `eshell-bol`, which is bound to `C-a` by default. It moves the cursor to the end of the prompt on the current line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

```lisp
(defun move-to-read-only-end ()
  "..."
  (interactive)
  (goto-char (or (next-single-property-change (point) 'read-only)
                 (line-end-position))))
```

Here, function `next-single-property-change` gives you the first position where property `read-only` changes its value.  Or it gives you `nil`, in which case you go to the end of the line.